# Unpack arguments into a command line flags using shell script

Tags: mongodb, bash, shell, mongodump, mongorestore

I am trying to create a shell script that will unpack multiple arguments and put them in a one-line with multiple flags

```bash
# How script will be run
./script "database" "collection1 collection2 collection3"
```

```bash
# Inside ./scipt
db=$1
collections=$2

mongodump --uri=<host:port> --db=${db} --collection=${for each argument in collections variable}

# Output should be this:
mongodump --uri=<host:port> --db=${db} --collection=collection1 --collection=collection2 --collection=collection3
```

The problem is how to unpack the `${collections}` variable which takes space-separated arguments into an array or something and calls each collection together with the `--collection` flag in one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `./script` might be something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

db=$1
read -ra collections <<< "$2"

echo mongodump --uri=host:port --db="$db" "${collections[@]/#/--collections=}"
```

Drop the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.
Run it as

```
./script "database" "collection1 collection2 collection3"
```

**Explanation:**

- The `<<< string` construct is called *here string*. The value of the string after expansions is supplied to the command on its standard input (See [Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)). Here strings can be used in any command (They are not special to `read`).
- The `-a collections` option of `read` means that the words of the input are assigned to sequential indices of the array variable *collections* (any valid variable name could be used).
  See [read Bash Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read).
- `"${collections[@]/#/--collections=}"` constructs a list whose each item is the consecutive element of the array `collections` prepended with the string `--collections=`.
   See [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (the section starting with **${parameter/pattern/string}**) and [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).

Comment: Hey @M. Nejat Aydin This works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you could give a brief explanation of your solution, especially the `collections <<< "$2"` and `"${collections[@]/#/--collections=}"` part

Comment: @sharhan-alhassan Added a brief explanation and links to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the array using IFS (Internal Field Separator), which uses space by default. Then you can loop the arguments in the array

```
#!/bin/bash

db=$1
collections=($2)

mongodump --uri=<host:port> --db=${db} "${collections[@]/#/--collection=}"
```

Comment: This answer is almost the same as mine but may fail if the arguments contains glob characters.

Comment: I had started typing my answer (and validating it before i contributed) but ya the collections loop is the same but the IFS array split is much more straight forward. Do you want me to delete my answer and edit yours as yours did go through first?

Comment: It is straight forward but not robust. Put it in the [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) and see. Or call it with `./script database '*'`

Comment: fair enough. just tryin to catch some reputation to be able to comment on top level posts. upvoted your answer as your argument is sound.